# Android Studio the emulator process for ..... has been terminated

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, average

I know this question apppeared a lot, but I spent the last like 3-4 hours trying a fix and nothing seemed to work so far. I tried reinstalling everything multiple times. I set my ANDROID_SDK_ROOT to my sdk folder, in the log file it still says that's the AVD system path is broken and I need to check it. I think that's the main issue, but I have no idea how to solve it. (My profile has unicode characters so I couldn't install to the appdata like everyone else. I think the problem somehow has to line up with that, but I set it to C:\Android and I set the root value exactly that. I have no idea what could be still the problem)

This is my "idea.log" file, I don't know what could help trying to solve this.

```
2021-12-04 15:23:19,053 [  18001]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: C:\Android\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5_API_25 -qt-hide-window -grpc-use-token -idle-grpc-timeout 300 
2021-12-04 15:23:19,632 [  18580]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [C:\Android]! 
2021-12-04 15:23:19,632 [  18580]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: INFO    | Android emulator version 31.1.4.0 (build_id 7920983) (CL:N/A) 
2021-12-04 15:23:19,633 [  18581]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1 
2021-12-04 15:23:19,633 [  18581]   WARN - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator terminated with exit code 1 
2021-12-04 15:23:20,443 [  19391]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 5017ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: 1/5 sluggish 
2021-12-04 15:23:20,463 [  19411]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Unindexed files update started: 0 files to index 
2021-12-04 15:23:21,509 [  20457]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Clearing symbols finished in 1 s 36 ms 
2021-12-04 15:23:21,529 [  20477]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading Header Maps finished in 18 ms 
2021-12-04 15:23:21,533 [  20481]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading Headers Search Roots finished in 1 ms 
2021-12-04 15:23:21,590 [  20538]   INFO - .jetbrains.cidr.lang.modulemap - Loaded 0 module maps in 0 packs for 0 search roots 
2021-12-04 15:23:21,591 [  20539]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading Module Maps finished in 57 ms 
2021-12-04 15:23:21,823 [  20771]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loaded 0 tables for 0 files (0 project files) 
2021-12-04 15:23:21,823 [  20771]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading symbols finished in 230 ms 
2021-12-04 15:23:21,835 [  20783]   INFO - .jetbrains.cidr.lang.modulemap - Building module maps for 0 (root, configuration) pairs 
2021-12-04 15:23:21,844 [  20792]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building module maps finished in 2 ms 
2021-12-04 15:23:21,844 [  20792]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Processing module maps finished in 0 ms 
2021-12-04 15:23:21,846 [  20794]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saved 0 module maps in 0 packs 
2021-12-04 15:23:21,851 [  20799]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving Module Maps finished in 6 ms 
2021-12-04 15:23:21,853 [  20801]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols for 0 source files 
2021-12-04 15:23:21,861 [  20809]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Updating symbols finished in 1 ms 
2021-12-04 15:23:21,861 [  20809]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols for 0 unused headers 
2021-12-04 15:23:21,861 [  20809]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Updating symbols finished in 0 ms 
2021-12-04 15:23:21,861 [  20809]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Updating symbols finished in 0 ms 
2021-12-04 15:23:21,862 [  20810]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols in FAST mode, 0 source files from total 0 project files 
2021-12-04 15:23:21,868 [  20816]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving modified symbols for 0 files (0 tables of total 0) 
2021-12-04 15:23:21,872 [  20820]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving symbols finished in 9 ms 
2021-12-04 15:23:22,167 [  21115]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/jre 
2021-12-04 15:23:22,255 [  21203]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/jre 
2021-12-04 15:23:22,293 [  21241]   INFO - g.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.script - [KOTLIN_SCRIPTING] Loading script definitions [org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.KotlinInitScript] using classpath: C:\Users\Leskó Zsolt\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-7.0.2-bin\857tjihv64xamwrf0h14cai3r\gradle-7.0.2\lib\gradle-core-7.0.2.jar;C:\Users\Leskó Zsolt\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-7.0.2-bin\857tjihv64xamwrf0h14cai3r\gradle-7.0.2\lib\gradle-core-api-7.0.2.jar;C:\Users\Leskó Zsolt\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-7.0.2-bin\857tjihv64xamwrf0h14cai3r\gradle-7.0.2\lib\gradle-kotlin-dsl-7.0.2.jar;C:\Users\Leskó Zsolt\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-7.0.2-bin\857tjihv64xamwrf0h14cai3r\gradle-7.0.2\lib\gradle-kotlin-dsl-tooling-models-7.0.2.jar;C:\Users\Leskó Zsolt\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-7.0.2-bin\857tjihv64xamwrf0h14cai3r\gradle-7.0.2\lib\kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.4.31-patched-for-gradle-7.0.2.jar 
2021-12-04 15:23:22,488 [  21436]   INFO - testKnownPluginVersionProvider - 'gradle' plugin missing from the offline Maven repo, will use default 7.0.3 
2021-12-04 15:23:22,491 [  21439]   INFO - idGradleProjectStartupActivity - Up-to-date models found in the cache. Not invoking Gradle sync. 
2021-12-04 15:23:22,502 [  21450]   INFO - testKnownPluginVersionProvider - 'gradle' plugin missing from the offline Maven repo, will use default 7.0.3 
2021-12-04 15:23:22,897 [  21845]   INFO - ativeWorkspaceModificationTask - NDK support for project 'lotto' is disabled because the project doesn't contain any valid native configurations. 
2021-12-04 15:23:22,913 [  21861]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/jre 
2021-12-04 15:23:22,917 [  21865]   INFO - g.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.script - [KOTLIN_SCRIPTING] Loading script definitions [org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.KotlinSettingsScript] using classpath: C:\Users\Leskó Zsolt\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-7.0.2-bin\857tjihv64xamwrf0h14cai3r\gradle-7.0.2\lib\gradle-core-7.0.2.jar;C:\Users\Leskó Zsolt\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-7.0.2-bin\857tjihv64xamwrf0h14cai3r\gradle-7.0.2\lib\gradle-core-api-7.0.2.jar;C:\Users\Leskó Zsolt\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-7.0.2-bin\857tjihv64xamwrf0h14cai3r\gradle-7.0.2\lib\gradle-kotlin-dsl-7.0.2.jar;C:\Users\Leskó Zsolt\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-7.0.2-bin\857tjihv64xamwrf0h14cai3r\gradle-7.0.2\lib\gradle-kotlin-dsl-tooling-models-7.0.2.jar;C:\Users\Leskó Zsolt\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-7.0.2-bin\857tjihv64xamwrf0h14cai3r\gradle-7.0.2\lib\kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.4.31-patched-for-gradle-7.0.2.jar 
2021-12-04 15:23:23,009 [  21957]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/jre 
2021-12-04 15:23:23,013 [  21961]   INFO - g.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.script - [KOTLIN_SCRIPTING] Loading script definitions [org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.KotlinBuildScript] using classpath: C:\Users\Leskó Zsolt\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-7.0.2-bin\857tjihv64xamwrf0h14cai3r\gradle-7.0.2\lib\gradle-core-7.0.2.jar;C:\Users\Leskó Zsolt\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-7.0.2-bin\857tjihv64xamwrf0h14cai3r\gradle-7.0.2\lib\gradle-core-api-7.0.2.jar;C:\Users\Leskó Zsolt\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-7.0.2-bin\857tjihv64xamwrf0h14cai3r\gradle-7.0.2\lib\gradle-kotlin-dsl-7.0.2.jar;C:\Users\Leskó Zsolt\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-7.0.2-bin\857tjihv64xamwrf0h14cai3r\gradle-7.0.2\lib\gradle-kotlin-dsl-tooling-models-7.0.2.jar;C:\Users\Leskó Zsolt\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-7.0.2-bin\857tjihv64xamwrf0h14cai3r\gradle-7.0.2\lib\kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.4.31-patched-for-gradle-7.0.2.jar
```